Why is MapStruct Processor sometimes added as a Maven plugin instead of a dependency?
Description:
I noticed a difference between the official MapStruct documentation and various tutorials regarding how to configure the mapstruct-processor. In some tutorials, the mapstruct-processor is added as a regular dependency under <dependencies>. However, the official documentation places it within the <maven-compiler-plugin> using <annotationProcessorPaths>.
My questions are:

Is it necessary for a dependency to be listed under <dependencies> for Maven to download and use it?
If the mapstruct-processor is only specified inside the <plugin>, how does Maven ensure it gets downloaded and used correctly?
What are the practical differences between these two approaches, and which one is recommended for a project using MapStruct?

I'm trying to understand the rationale behind these configurations and their implications.

(1) Don't believe so. (2) Probably via the same mechanism used for <dependencies>. (3) If I'm not mistaken, defining the annotation processor in the plugin configuration ensures the processor is placed on the --processor-path or --processor-module-path, and possibly sets the -processor option as well. This is important as I believe annotation processors will stop being automatically being picked up from the class-path in a future version (if it hasn't happened already) and they were never automatically picked up from the module-path.

Hi! @Slaw thanks in advance for your fast reply. So, would you recommend following the official documentation and placing the processor under the plugin configuration instead of directly in the dependencies section? Is this primarily due to potential future changes in Maven's behavior and for consistency purposes?

The answer to question 2 can be found at https://github.com/apache/maven-compiler-plugin/blob/maven-compiler-plugin-3.13.0/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/AbstractCompilerMojo.java#L1672: the plugin asks Maven to download them through the dependency mechanism, but without making them available as dependencies. That keeps them unavailable to your source code, and won't add them to your application.

I would follow the official documentation, both for the reason I mentioned (note that's a change in Java, or at least javac, not Maven) and the reason Rob mentions (prevent annotation processor from leaking into your project code and/or being exposed transitively).

Thank you both for your clarifications. I will follow your advice and place the annotation processor under the plugin, as suggested in the documentation, to ensure consistency and to be prepared for future changes in Java's behavior.
